# SQL HAVING can't find the column unknown column

Tags: php, sql, laravel

```
return $this
    ->restaurant
    ->select('restaurants.*')
    ->selectRaw('COALESCE(ROUND(AVG(reviews.rating),1), 0) as average_rating')
    ->leftJoin('reviews', 'reviews.restaurant_id', '=', 'restaurants.id')
    ->when($user_id, function($query, $user_id){
        $query->where("restaurants.user_id", $user_id);
    })
    ->groupBy('restaurants.id')
    ->when($request->from_rating, function($query, $from_rating){
        $query->having('average_rating', '>=', $from_rating);
    })
    ->when($request->to_rating, function($query, $to_rating){
        $query->having('average_rating', '<=', $to_rating);
    })->orderByDesc("average_rating")
    ->paginate(
        $this->perPage, 
        ['id', 'name', 'image', 'description', 'filesystem', 'created_at'], 
        'page', 
        $request->page
    );
```

This is the query I am facing. Finally. I made it work, but now problem is look at the following line,

```
$query->having('average_rating', '>=', $from_rating);
```

This throws error: `unknown column average_rating`. I have no idea why. I have this column in select above.

I also transformed this to SQL statement using toSql() function.

Result:

```
select 
    `restaurants`.*, 
    COALESCE(ROUND(AVG(reviews.rating),1), 0) as average_rating 
from 
    `restaurants` 
     left join `reviews` on `reviews`.`restaurant_id` = `restaurants`.`id` 
group by `restaurants`.`id` 
having `average_rating` >= ? and `average_rating` <= ? 
order by `average_rating` desc
```

Comment: Can you include the rest of the stack trace for that error?

Answer (score 1):

Column aliases that are defined in the `SELECT` clause are not allowed in `HAVING` clause. This is due to the order in which the RDBMS evaluates the differents parts of the query : the `HAVING` clause is evaluated before the `SELECT` clause, as opposite, for example, to the `ORDER BY` clause, which is processed later (and hence accepts columns aliases)

You would need to change this part of your query:

```
$query->having('average_rating', '>=', $from_rating);
```

To:

```
$query->having('COALESCE(ROUND(AVG(reviews.rating),1), 0)', '>=', $from_rating);
```

Comment: If they are not allowed, then why does it work in plain mysql?

Comment: select `restaurants`.*, COALESCE(ROUND(AVG(reviews.rating),1), 0) as average_rating from `restaurants` left join `reviews` on `reviews`.`restaurant_id` = `restaurants`.`id` group by `restaurants`.`id` having `average_rating` >= 3 and `average_rating` <= 7 order by `average_rating` desc

Comment: I commented sql query. it works in plain sql. so your answer seems wrong.